# Mysterious auto edit of .vimrc

Tags: vimrc

I have a mysterious, troubling, and extremely irritating problem with what might be called auto-edits of my **vimrc** file.

It only happens when I open **vimrc** file from buffer list (ie there are a number of buffers listed) or with `:e vimrc`.

It only happens very occasionally and so is almost impossible to debug.

What happens is, when opening my **vimrc** file from the bufferlist, the first thing that happens is one char is deleted in normal mode wherever the cursor happens to be (I have a very standard function in **vimrc** to place cursor at last position).

I'm getting good at spotting it when it *does* happen but I've missed it in the past and it's created huge problems; it is, after all, my **vimrc** file and pretty massive at that (currently 3700+ lines)!

If I could somehow initiate a debugging session when I see it happening (because when it *does* happen, I can switch between buffers and watch it happen again and again), but if I ever try to start vim in verbose mode (eg. `gvim -V9myVim.log`) I've never managed to replicate the issue.

It's so frustrating and I'm beginning to believe it's not just 'accidental' (portentous squinting and furrowing of brow).

Please help!

VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Sep  9 2018 01:29:11)
MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support
Included patches: 1-354

Comment: Please mention what Vim version, what terminal you are using and what is $TERM set to?

Comment: Please try with a more uptodate vim first

Comment: Are you sure there isn't some autocmd in your huge vimrc (possibly from a plugin)? That would be my first suspect anyway. You can see all autocmds for the vim filetype with `:au FileType vim`; although it could also be on some other event (use `:au` to see all of them, but it will probably be a long list, you can add it to a buffer with `:call setline('.', execute('au')->split('\n'))` and then search for `vim` maybe). But like Christian said: I'd try with a newer Vim first; 8.1.354 is almost three years old.

Comment: Do you have any mappings on escape?

Comment: _possibly_ relevant (and for your other question, too): [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)

Comment: As stated, I've removed edit markers. Editing your version info was very helpful. The reply to let us know you're off looking for a culprit could have been a comment, however, and I removed it.

Comment: I attempted to update Vim just recently to 8.2 but had massive problem with conflicts with python install. For whatever reason, *my* Vim has support for a more recent version of python than the latest Windows installer. Anyway, I gave up.

Comment: Like I said, this problem happens only very occasionally. Trying to debug my vimrc etc is impracticable. I need a way of debugging **when the problem happens and with the current config**. I'm guessing the best way would be to run Vim with logging **all the time** and wait for the problem to happen and then go look at the logfile. Any suggestion what log level would be suitable?